# Docker: "Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: unable to list exposed ports"

Tags: docker, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new in Docker, I have created a WebAPI in .Net Core and trying to deploy it on Docker.

I have build docker image successfully

```
PS F:\Projects\dockerAPI> docker build -t dockerapi .
```

Now getting bellow error while running docker image on container.

```
PS F:\Projects\dockerAPI> docker run -p 8080:80 dockerapi
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: unable to list exposed ports: Get http://unix/forwards/list: open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendApiServer: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

DockerFile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerAPI.dll"]
```